# Maximum likelihood and degenerate Fisher information

Tags: maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

I am wondering if there are some standard results to find rates of convergence of the MLE for different sub-parameters, when the Fisher information is degenerate.

More precisely, suppose that I consider a parametric model with parameter $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)\in\mathbb R^k\times \mathbb R^{d-k}$ and I suppose that the Fisher information matrix, evaluated at the true parameter $\theta^*$, is degenerate, with nullspace $\{0\}\times\mathbb R^{d-k}$. If $\hat\theta=(\hat\theta_1,\hat\theta_2)$ is the MLE, I want to evaluate the rates of convergence of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ separately.